# Something's deleting 3 elements from my ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

As part of homework, we have to implement a merge sort. No big deal, I've done it before. This time, though I'm getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Still no big deal, not hard to fix.

But I do a little digging, and I end up with the following code in a while loop in my merge method:

```
private static void merge(ArrayList<T> data, int first, int mid, int last) {
    ArrayList<T> temp = new ArrayList<T>();
    int first1 = first, last1 = mid;
    int first2 = mid+1, last2 = last;
    int index = first1;

    while (first1 <= last1 && first2 <= last2) {
       System.out.println("still in while loop");
       System.out.println(data);
        
        if (data.get(first1).compareTo(data.get(first2)) < 0) {
            temp.add(index, data.get(first1));
            first1++;
        } else {
           temp.add(index, data.get(first2));
           first2++;
        }
           index++;
           System.out.println(data);
    }

            
    while (first1 <= last1) {
        temp.set(index, data.get(first1));
        first1++;
        index++;
    }
    
    while (first2 <= last2) {
        temp.set(index, data.get(first2));
        first2++;
        index++;
    }
    
    data.clear();
    for (index=first; index <= last; index++)
        data.add(index, temp.get(index));
}
```

The output ends up something like:

> still in while loop
>
> [8800, 2596, 7518, 9900, 7164]
>
> [8800, 2596, 7518, 9900, 7164]
>
> still in while loop
>
> [2596, 8800]
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2

<strike>So, something's happening between the last line before it loops and the first two lines in the while loop that deletes 3 numbers from my ArrayList. The problem is: I can't imagine what. I'm not removing any data in the while loop at all; I'm only adding data to a different ArrayList. The while condition has nothing to do with the ArrayList. In short, I'm lost.</strike>

The bug is in the later part of the method, apparently. I still don't know what's up, and the stack trace for the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` still points to a line in the while loop (specifically `if (data.get(first1).compareTo(data.get(first2)) < 0) {`), but it's only reproducible if that code's there. So I'm still lost.

What's up here? How do I fix it?

Comment: Is there another (concurrent) thread that could be modifying this variable? Is this problem reproducible?

Comment: no concurrent threads, and it is reproducible, but the bug is in the later part of my method, which I'm adding now

Comment: what are the values of first, mid, and last when you call the function merge?

Comment: I've been passing it 0, 2, 4 when debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, my problem was that I wasn't tracing the flow of control properly. I thought I was staying in the while loop, but actually, I was breaking out, and `data.clear()` was, surprise surprise, clearing the ArrayList.
My solution was to replace the last two lines in the method with:

```
for (index=first; index <= last; index++)
        data.set(index, temp.get(index));
```

It works now.